# Unable to fix GRUB for dual-boot after BIOS update (using boot-repair)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bios, boot-repair

After my latest update of BIOS (while using Windows) my grub menu went missing.
Previously, I was able to repair GRUB menu this way:

- Booting into Windows
- Going to Advanced Startup options
- Selecting my Ubuntu partition there
- Getting advanced restart -> Seeing my GRUB menu.

Then, I was able to select Ubuntu OS, log in, run boot-repair and get my GRUB menu back.

However, this time when I try to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed linux-signed*
```

(as boot-repair recommends me), I get an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package grub-reinstall_programs
```

So, I can't purge my GRUB and repair its menu... I have no idea how to fix this error and not to mess up with it even more. Please, help!

*Additional info:
I have Ubuntu 14.04 and a pre-installed Windows 8.1 on my PC.*

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the command, replace `grub*` by `grub-common`. The error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

insert an Ubuntu Live DVD or CD

Choose the Option Try Ubuntu

Allow it to start up. now lets Start

This solution is suitable after a bios update or after repartitioning your hard disk or both. if after one of these actions you get the grub error 17 message kindly follow the steps below. Some situations might not required all the steps, but others might need it. however following these steps will do no harm even if you don't need it.

open a terminal "ctrl + alt + T" then type the following commands within the quotation signs followed by enter

1. "sudo fdisk -l"
2. "sudo fdisk /dev/hda" OR "sudo fdisk /dev/sda" 
   Use sda or hda depending on what the output of command line 1. says
3. "x"
4. "f"
5. "w"

close the terminal.

open a new terminal "ctrl + alt + T" then type the following command within the quotation signs followed by enter

1. "sudo fdisk -l"

Identify the partition with "linux" at the end, not the one with "linux swap/Solaris"

write down the sdaX or hdaX code where "X" is a number

e.g. hda2 is (hd0,1) in grub and

```
 sda2 is (hd0,1) in grub
```

simillarly sda5 or hda5 is (hd0,4) in grub

it is the grub code you'll need.

your grub code should be in the form (hd0,W) where W is a number

close the terminal

Connect to the internet

open a new terminal "ctrl + alt + T" then type the following commands within the quotation signs followed by enter

1. "sudo apt-get install grub"
2. "Y"
3. "sudo grub"
4. "root (hd0,W)"
5. "setup (hd0)"
6. "quit"

close the terminal
- You might need to run startup repair with your windows installation dvd
- Grub Should be reinstalled and working properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the problem correctly but I lost my grub menu after bios update.There was no grub menu and it directly booted my windows.
(I had dual-booted Ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10). I accessed the advanced startup options after booting into windows(as given above). From the options I accessed the U.E.F.I settings, there I found both my software installed so I changed the priority by making Ubuntu the first one to be booted and when I saved the changes I could see my grub menu after restart.
(I just thought to check out what will happen if I changed this setting.)
I have no clue about boot-repair and don't know if I used it or not.